# How do you call a method and catch an error if it fails in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, methods, error-handling, brute-force

I'm using the npm module [express-brute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-brute) alongside [express-brute-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-brute-mongo) to prevent brute force attacks on a webapp I'm building.

When a user sends a request to our api, their IP is logged in an IP table stored on a remote mongo database (using express-brute-mongo) which works great!

Upon testing however, in the event that the mongoDB server cannot be reached from the node server:
A user sends a request to our api, which then reaches out to the MongoDB instance, but fails. This causes the node server to crash and no response is sent to the user.

Is it possible (& how) to try / catch any errors, then carry on processing the API request, and respond to the user?

The method called for express-brute is: .prevent (i.e. globalBruteforce.prevent)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can't you use a try catch ? Or a fail handler if it is a promise ?

Comment: No - you cant, as it can't be called in the standard manner. To call the function its; expressBrute.prevent. If you call it as a function (), errors are thrown.